# In React Native is there a way to recognize stylus (pen) vs touch (finger) event?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, uitouch

I'm working on the RN application that has one screen with a list of "drawable" areas in it. So this screen should be scrollable AND drawable.

What I'm trying to do - is to find a solution to distinguish touch events coming from **fingers** (these will be used to scroll and disallow drawing) and **stylus** via Apple Pencil (these will be used to draw and disallow scrolling).

In both Gesture Responder and PanResponder there are events being passed on each move. Each of those **events** (alongside with the **nativeEvent**) contains the **type** property. However, it's always null for me in both simulator and device.

Is there any way to recognize a move event as a finger vs stylus?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm facing the exact same issue right now.

Comment: @TatsuyaYokota Unfortunately, we couldn't find any pure React Native solution to this. We ended up implementing this functionality in Objective-C on the iOS side and pass the touch type to the React Native side. For the reference, this is for Xcode v9.2. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hia @Nadine  - We are having the same problem at Pencil Bible. We tried your idea ☝ - but it did not work. According to Matt our developer: "When a touch is registered via Native iOS, there is a delay between when the touch event is registered and when React Native receives that event. So, we cannot accurately determine if the touch was a pencil or finger." - do you have any insight - or can you do a paid consultation  #gettingdesperate

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar requirement for one of our projects, and what we did was to use a `Pressable` component, to which a handlePress function was passed as prop.
This function accepted the `GestureResponderEvent` as event callback argument.
By using the event.nativeEvent.altitudeAngle property that was [added recently](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f1b1ba8963ff152d995c3cd132bc0755413bc44f), we were able to detect Apple Pencil touches.

```
    function handlePress(event: GestureResponderEvent) {
    //@ts-expect-error React Native Types do not include altitudeAngle
    const isPencilTouch = !!event.nativeEvent.altitudeAngle;
    ...
}
```